# List all nodes which sub-node meta contains some value 123456

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I want my script below to output `Pdt 1` and `Pdt3` if their sub-node meta contains `123456`, but it outputs none. What's the right syntax?

I know problem comes from bad criteria syntax `@id='$_.id'` in

```psh
ForEach-Object {
    $meta = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//catalogue/produits/produit[@id='$_.id']/metas/meta[@code='$meta_code']")
}
```

which is part of whole script:

```psh
$xml=[xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<catalogue>
  <produits>
    <produit id="pdt1" libelle="produit 1" cat="PDT">
      <metas date="2015.07.24">
        <meta code="123456" value="123456"></meta>
        <meta code="789012" value="ghijkl"></meta>
        <meta code="345678" value="mnopqr"></meta>
      </metas>
    </produit>
    <produit id="pdt2" libelle="produit 2" cat="PDT">
      <metas date="2015.07.24">
        <meta code="123456" value="abcdef"></meta>
        <meta code="789012" value="ghijkl"></meta>
        <meta code="345678" value="mnopqr"></meta>
      </metas>
    </produit>
    <produit id="pdt3" libelle="produit 3" cat="PDT">
      <metas date="2015.07.24">
        <meta code="123456" value="123456"></meta>
        <meta code="789012" value="ghijkl"></meta>
        <meta code="345678" value="mnopqr"></meta>
      </metas>
    </produit>
  </produits>
</catalogue>
'@

$meta_code = "123456"

$xml.catalogue.produits.produit | where {$_.cat.startsWith("PDT")} | ForEach-Object {
    $meta = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//catalogue/produits/produit[@id='$_.id']/metas/meta[@code='$meta_code']")
    if($meta) {Write-Host $_.libelle "in"  $meta.code}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with your XQuery string:

```
$meta = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//catalogue/produits/produit[@id='$_.id']/metas/meta[@code='$meta_code']")
```

PowerShell interprets `$_.id` as `$_.ToString() + ".id"` which, in your case, ends up being `pdt1.id`. Of course, no nodes match that id.

Instead, wrap `$_.id` as an expression, `$($_.id)`:

```
$meta = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//catalogue/produits/produit[@id='$($_.id)']/metas/meta[@code='$meta_code']")
```

Or, better yet, use the `-f` string format operator:

```
$xquery = "//catalogue/produits/produit[@id='{0}']/metas/meta[@code='{1}']" -f $_.id,$meta_code
$meta = $xml.SelectSingleNode($xQuery)
```

You could forgo the call to `SelectSingleNode` completely, because you've already got the node in your `ForEach-Object` script block. You can find the meta node you want with:

```
$xml.catalogue.produits.produit |
    Where-Object { $_.cat -like 'PDT*' } |
    ForEach-Object { 
        $produit = $_
        $meta = $produit.metas.meta | Where-Object { $_.code -eq $meta_code }
        if( $meta )
        {
            Write-Host -Message ('{0} in {1}' -f $produit.libelle,$meta.code)
        }
    }
```

Comment: When I try, It outputs all 3 Pdt instead of 2 Pdt.

Comment: @user310291 Try without using SelectSingleNode. Updated my answer with a possible solution. Also, what is the output you're getting?

Answer (score 2):

If you put `$_.id` inside a string, PowerShell expands only `$_` to its string representation. The `.id` remains as a literal string. To have the `id` property of the current object expanded in the string you need to use a subexpression:

```
"//catalogue/produits/produit[@id='$($_.id)']/metas/meta[@value='$meta_code']"
```

With that said, from the looks of it you want to select the `libelle` attribute of products whose `cat` attribute starts with the letters `PDT` and which contain a `<meta>` node whose `value` attribute has the value specified in the variable `$meta_code`. If that's the case you can condense your entire code into a single [XPath expression](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.3/expressions.html):

```
$meta_code = "123456"
$xpath = "//catalogue/produits/produit" +
         "[starts-with(@cat,'PDT') and metas/meta/@value='$meta_code']"
$xml.SelectNodes($xpath) | % { '{0} in {1}' -f $_.libelle, $meta_code }
```

Comment: $($_.id) outputs all 3 Pdt instead of 2 Pdt.

Comment: @user310291 Ah, so you want the elements where the `value` attribute (not the `code` attribute) has the value specified in `$meta_code`. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this Xpath -- 
"//produits/poduit/@id[./meta[@code = '123456']]"