# Why Powershell does not evaluate the expression

Tags: string, powershell

Instead of writing this

```
$criteria = 'id=' + '"' + $pdt_code + '"'
```

I'd like to have something like this :

```
$criteria = 'id="$($pdt_code)"'
```

But Powershell does not evaluate the expression, why : What's the right syntax ?

Why this works and not the above (see [List all nodes which sub-node meta contains some value 123456](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842090/list-all-nodes-which-sub-node-meta-contains-some-value-123456)) ?

```
$meta = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//catalogue/produits/produit[@id='$($_.id)']/metas/meta[@code='$meta_code']")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only variables that are inside double quoted strings `"..."` will be evaluated. Your string is a single quoted one:

```
$criteria = 'id="$($pdt_code)"'
#           ^  single quotes  ^
```

You should instead write:

```
$criteria = "id=""$pdt_code"""
```

Note too that you need to double the `"` characters inside the string so that PowerShell treats them as literal `"` characters and not the end of the string.

---

Your second example works because it is using a double quoted string (which evaluate variables):

```
$meta = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//catalogue/produits/produit[@id='$($_.id)']/metas/meta[@code='$meta_code']")
#                             ^   double quotes                                                           ^
```

When parsing a string literal, PowerShell only cares about what quote characters are on the ends of a string.

Comment: Thanks. Can you answer my subsequent question in my update ? There is no need to double quote in the other example.

Comment: @user310291 - See my edit. You are actually using a double quoted string in the second example.